# Django's general setup() function

Tags: django

I was reading the Django [logging docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) and came across this line:

> Logging is configured as part of the general Django setup() function. Therefore, you can be certain that loggers are always ready for use in your project code.

Which **general `setup()` function** is being talked about here? 
Does this function execute only once at startup, making it the best entry point hook to add custom code?

How is it different from the `MyAppConfig` defined in `apps.py`.

Comment: What custom code are you talking about? Its hard to say where to put code if there isn't any indication on what that code does

Comment: I wish to initiate my cache with a key. This will be common for the entire project. I didn't want to use `get_or_set()` later.

Answer (score 3):

It's referring to the [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) method.

I have never seen it overridden, so I wouldn't use it as an entry point to add custom code there.

There's an explanation of what the `setup()` method does in the docs on [how applications are loaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded). As it explains, Django runs the [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method of each app config at the end of the process. You could create an app config class, and put your custom code there.

Answer (score 3):

Its found in djangos [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py), it is the first thing that is called from [`get_wsgi_application`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/wsgi.py)

Comment: Yes, makes sense. They do configure logging [there](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py#L22)

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary - Yes, using [this method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L66). If you wished to delve deeper in the inner workings of the code I'd suggest using an ide that lets you click through paths. Although the [page you can get to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.setup) from Alasdairs answer is probably much simpler to understand